# How to create non-existing file with content then save it as binary in a database?

Tags: c#, file, byte, attachment, filestream

So I have a database which has an attachments table, inside that I have a binary column which stores the actual file. 
I am wanting to generate a file within my code, add content to this file and save it to my database as binary data without having a physical file saved.
So for I have this code

```
var fileString = "Some random file content string";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileString);
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

This creates the binary of the file content, however when I do come to save the file, it is a *.bin file as there was no code to say what type of file it was. 
How can I wrap the contents of the string with a file which can then be saved as a binary file?


Please don't suggest alternatives, I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I have extreme limitations with this system I am using.
Thanks

Comment: quite confusing description. you want to save to database? then you can save the generated `bytes` directly to your database. why are you using `MemoryStream`?

Comment: I have some generic code which takes a Memory steam in order to actually save the file to the database.  Its not ideal, but its what I have to work with.

Comment: you can use [MemoryStream.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert to `byte array` which you can store to database.

Comment: Thats not the problem I am having.  I just need to save the contents as a file.  At the moment when I come to download the file, its a binary file.  I need to save the contents with my own file name and extension

Comment: database binary field just takes binary data. no filename. if you want to store filename ext length etc you should have other columns to store those. (I still didn't understand your question)

Comment: Hmm, Ok.  Maybe I'm reading this database wrong.  
Don't worry, I've been fixing this system for a year and I still don't understand it.  The creators has no idea what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
var fileString = "Some random file content string";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileString);
File.WriteAllBytes(pathToFile, bytes);
```

Comment: But this will create a physical file, I just need the resulting binary data of having a file converted to binary.  I can't have a physical file.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass your file data like byte array to the sql parameter value.

all you have to do is 
create DbCommand successor (like SqlCommand for MS SQL server)
add command text like 'insert into attachments (attachid, content) values (@aid, @c)'
create parameters instances

```
var p = command.CreateParameter();
p.ParameterName = "@c";
p.Value = bytes;
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Binary;
command.Parameters.Add(p);
```

(the same for all other parameters)
and then execute command.ExecNonQuery();
this will put string value as byte array to the data table attachments in your database.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but after talking with 'bansi' I realised that the file name is not passed with the binary data.  I've not managed to pass it through separately.  
Thanks for the comment though, it could be useful for someone else still :)

Comment: @Ben you can save file name at the same as file contents using some separator. Or you can save file name length at the beginning of the stream, then save file name to the stream and then - save file content. However you will have to read length and remove file name each time when you are going to get file content. Or you can zip original file (zip archive can contains original file name) and save zip to the DB. But the best way is to have separate column for file name in the same table that holds file data.